# SwiftUI - Sorting a structured array and show date item into a Section Header

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, swiftui, grouping

I'm trying to show some section Header which is based on data in my structured array.

When I add a value in my array from my app I ask to enter a date. This one is save as a String cause I don't know how to save it differently from a Textfield..

So in my array I've got an enter "date" formatting like : `DD/MM/YYYY`

Now I need to have a view where I list all the array Items sorting by date, where the most recent date is show on the top of the screen and more the user scroll down more the date is far in a past.

So my structured array is defined like that :

```
struct Flight: Identifiable{
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    
    let date: String
    
    let depPlace: String
    let arrPlace: String

    
    init (date: String, depPlace: String, arrPlace: String){
        self.date = date
        
        self.depPlace = depPlace
        self.arrPlace = arrPlace

    }
    
    init(config: NewFlightConfig){
        self.date = config.date
        
        self.depPlace = config.depPlace
        self.arrPlace = config.arrPlace
        
    }
    
}
```

and `NewFlightConfig` :

```
struct NewFlightConfig{

    var date: String = ""

    var depPlace: String = ""
    var arrPlace: String = ""

}
```

The `TextField` where I ask for the date :

```
TextField("DD/MM/YYYY", text: $flightConfig.date)
     .padding()
     .background(.white)
     .cornerRadius(20.0)
     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
     .onReceive(Just(flightConfig.date)) { inputValue in
               if inputValue.count > 10 {
                       self.flightConfig.date.removeLast()
               }else if inputValue.count == 2{
                       self.flightConfig.date.append("/")
               }else if inputValue.count == 5{
                       self.flightConfig.date.append("/")
               }
      }
```

Finally my Homepage with my list which is defined as follow :

```
ScrollView{
    VStack {
          ForEach(flightLibrary.testFlight) {date in
             Section(header: Text(date.date).font(.title2).fontWeight(.semibold)) {
                     ForEach(flightLibrary.testFlight) {flight in
                         ZStack {
                             RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous)
                                  .fill(Color.white)
                                  .shadow(color: Color(Color.RGBColorSpace.sRGB, white: 0, opacity: 0.2), radius: 4)
                                  LogbookCellView(flight: flight)                         
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 16)
                }
```

Where I've trying to deal with `Dictionary` to fill the SectionHeader Text but seems to didn't work...

```
var entryCollatedByDate: [String : [Flight]] {
        Dictionary(grouping: flightLibrary, by: { $0.date })
     }
```

I'm not very familiar with how to sorted data and grouped data into arrays.

My final objectif is to have something like that :

```
Section Header 1 -> 15/09/2022 
        Array Items 1 -> last items with same Header date 
        Array Items 2 -> last items with same Header date 
Section Header 2 -> 14/09/2022 
        Array Items 3 -> last items with same Header date 
        Array Items 4 -> last items with same Header date 
        Array Items 5 -> last items with same Header date
[...]
Section Header N -> DD/MM/YYYY
        Array Items N -> last items with same Header date
```

Hope to be clear about my problem

Thanks for your help

Comment: Unfortunately the format `DD/MM/YYYY` cannot be sorted in a reasonable order. Consider to change it to `YYYY/MM/DD`. Or use a `DatePicker`.

Comment: Hi, If I use a `DatePicker` I need to save the date at `Date` format in my array that's right I never use it before but that's could be a good idea. And if it can simplify the sorting why not using it !

Comment: I have got published a new answer with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach, where a function `func asDate(...)` is used to transform your `String` date
to a `Date` on the fly. Then using `Set` and `map`, to get unique dates for the sections.
These unique dates are sorted using the `func asDate(...)`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var flightLibrary = [Flight(date: "14/09/2022", depPlace: "depPlace-1", arrPlace: "arrPlace-1"),
                                Flight(date: "15/09/2022", depPlace: "depPlace-2", arrPlace: "arrPlace-2"),
                                Flight(date: "12/09/2022", depPlace: "depPlace-3", arrPlace: "arrPlace-3"),
                                Flight(date: "14/09/2022", depPlace: "depPlace-1.2", arrPlace: "arrPlace-1.2")]
  
    func asDate(_ str: String) -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        return dateFormatter.date(from: str) ?? Date()
    }

    @State var uniqueDates = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack {
                ForEach(uniqueDates, id: \.self) { date in
                    Section(header: Text(date).font(.title2).fontWeight(.semibold)) {
                        ForEach(flightLibrary.filter({$0.date == date})) { flight in
                            ZStack {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous)
                                    .fill(Color.white)
                                    .shadow(color: Color(Color.RGBColorSpace.sRGB, white: 0, opacity: 0.2), radius: 4)
                                Text(flight.arrPlace)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal, 16)
        }
        .onAppear {
            // unique and sorted dates
            uniqueDates = Array(Set(flightLibrary.map{$0.date})).sorted(by: {asDate($0) > asDate($1)})
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative approach is to change the `String` date in `Flight` to type `Date`.
Then using `Set`, `map` and `sorted`, to get unique and sorted dates for the sections.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var flightLibrary = [Flight]()
    @State var uniqueDates = [Date]()
    let frmt = DateFormatter()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack {
                ForEach(uniqueDates, id: \.self) { date in
                    Section(header: Text(frmt.string(from: date)).font(.title2).fontWeight(.semibold)) {
                      ForEach(flightLibrary.filter({Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: date)})) { flight in
                            ZStack {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous)
                                    .fill(Color.white)
                                    .shadow(color: Color(Color.RGBColorSpace.sRGB, white: 0, opacity: 0.2), radius: 4)
                                Text(flight.arrPlace)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal, 16)
        }
        .onAppear {
            frmt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
            frmt.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

            // for testing only
            flightLibrary = [Flight(date: frmt.date(from: "14/09/2022")!, depPlace: "depPlace-1", arrPlace: "arrPlace-1"),
                             Flight(date: frmt.date(from: "15/09/2022")!, depPlace: "depPlace-2", arrPlace: "arrPlace-2"),
                             Flight(date: frmt.date(from: "12/09/2022")!, depPlace: "depPlace-3", arrPlace: "arrPlace-3"),
                             Flight(date: frmt.date(from: "14/09/2022")!, depPlace: "depPlace-1.2", arrPlace: "arrPlace-1.2")]
            
            // unique and sorted dates
            uniqueDates = Array(Set(flightLibrary.map{$0.date})).sorted(by: {$0 > $1})
        }
    }
}
 
 struct Flight: Identifiable, Hashable {
     let id = UUID().uuidString
     let date: Date // <-- here
     let depPlace: String
     let arrPlace: String

     init (date: Date, depPlace: String, arrPlace: String){ // <-- here
         self.date = date
         self.depPlace = depPlace
         self.arrPlace = arrPlace
     }

     init(config: NewFlightConfig) { 
         self.date = config.date
         self.depPlace = config.depPlace
         self.arrPlace = config.arrPlace
     }
 }

 struct NewFlightConfig {
     var date: Date = Date()  // <-- here
     var depPlace: String = ""
     var arrPlace: String = ""
 }
```

EDIT-1: here is another approach that uses a `class FlightModel: ObservableObject`
to hold your data and update the UI whenever `flights` is changed. It also has a convenience computed property for the`uniqueDates`.
So in your `addView`, pass the `flightModel` to it (e.g @EnvironmentObject) and add new `Flight` to the `flightModel`.

```
class FlightModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var flights = [Flight]()

var uniqueDates: [Date] {
    let arr = flights.compactMap{frmt.date(from: frmt.string(from: $0.date))}
    return Array(Set(arr.map{$0})).sorted(by: {$0 > $1})
}
    
    let frmt = DateFormatter()
    
    init() {
        frmt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        frmt.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        getData()
    }
    
    func getData() {
        // for testing only
    flights = [
        Flight(date: Date(), depPlace: "LFLI", arrPlace: "LFLP"),
        Flight(date: Date(), depPlace: "LFLP", arrPlace: "LFLB"),
        Flight(date: Date(), depPlace: "LFLB", arrPlace: "LFLG"),
        
        Flight(date: frmt.date(from: "14/09/2022")!, depPlace: "depPlace-1", arrPlace: "arrPlace-1"),
        Flight(date: frmt.date(from: "15/09/2022")!, depPlace: "depPlace-2", arrPlace: "arrPlace-2"),
        Flight(date: frmt.date(from: "12/09/2022")!, depPlace: "depPlace-3", arrPlace: "arrPlace-3"),
        Flight(date: frmt.date(from: "14/09/2022")!, depPlace: "depPlace-1.2", arrPlace: "arrPlace-1.2")
    ]
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var flightModel = FlightModel()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(flightModel.uniqueDates, id: \.self) { date in
                    Section(header: Text(flightModel.frmt.string(from: date)).font(.title2).fontWeight(.semibold)) {
                        ForEach(flightModel.flights.filter({Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: date)})) { flight in
                            ZStack {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous)
                                    .fill(Color.white)
                                    .shadow(color: Color(Color.RGBColorSpace.sRGB, white: 0, opacity: 0.2), radius: 4)
                                Text(flight.arrPlace)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal, 16)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tested the second option which look like to be better. But when I've 2 same date my scroll view show two time the same header with two the two object each time inside this section ..?

Comment: Also this not updating when I add a data via my addView I think it is because the code is `.onAppear` should I need to convert `uniqueDate` to an `@ObservableObject` ?

Comment: could you show the data (Flight/dates) that are not working when using my code. Also show a more complete example code that highlights your problems and any errors you get and on which line.

Comment: updated my answer with a new approach.

Comment: Right ! With the updated version directly included in my current FlightLibrary it work very very fine !!! Many thanks !

Comment: if my answer helped, could you mark it as accepted please, use the tick mark, it turns green.

Answer (score 0):

In response to @workingdog support Ukraine in the comments just before.

I have no errors in my code but with this array :

```
class FlightLibrary: ObservableObject{
       
    @Published var testFlight = [
        Flight(date: Date(), depPlace: "LFLI", arrPlace: "LFLP"),
        Flight(date: Date(), depPlace: "LFLP", arrPlace: "LFLB"),
        Flight(date: Date(), depPlace: "LFLB", arrPlace: "LFLG")      
    ]
    
}
```

This return something like :

```
Section Header 1 : Today Date 
   Item 1 :testFlight[0]
   Item 2 :testFlight[0]
   Item 3 :testFlight[0]
Section Header 2 : Today Date 
   Item 1 :testFlight[0]
   Item 2 :testFlight[0]
   Item 3 :testFlight[0]
```

When I append a value into testFlight, via a page in the app where user could fill some textFields to set date, dePlace and arrPlace, then dismiss my page the scrollview is not updated correctly. I've my new item but I have no Section Header ...

My add button code in the other view :

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
@ObservedObject var flightLibrary: FlightLibrary
@State var flightConfig = NewFlightConfig()
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
    let newFlight = Flight(config: flightConfig)
    flightLibrary.testFlight.append(newFlight)
    dismiss()
     }, label: {
          Text("Save")
    }))
```

To update the scrollview I go in an other page and back (to reload the `.onAppear`) to the page where I have my scrollview and now it works with all section header but !

If there is only one date section header is correct but if there is two or more item with the same date it create a new section header for each item but it add all the item with the same date in each section ...

Exemple :

```
Item1 = Date 1 
Item2 = Date 1
Item3 = Date 2
Item4 = Date 1 

result of : 

    Section Header 1 : Date1 
       Item 1 
       Item 2 
       Item 4 
    Section Header 2 : Date1 
       Item 1 
       Item 2 
       Item 4 
    Section Header 3 : Date1 
       Item 1 
       Item 2 
       Item 4 
    Section Header 4 : Date2 
       Item 3
```